# How Many Speedy Knights on a Chess Board?

Tags: chess

Similar to [How Many Knights on a Chess Board?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/how-many-knights-on-a-chess-board#) however speedy knights move the way the knight moves, then the way the knight moves AGAIN. However they cannot backtrack to their starting position. How many can you place on a board so to as none are being threatened.

For example, this 1 speedy knight, attacks all these kings:

[image]

Comment: Do they threaten the square they move to on their first move, or only the one they move to on their second move?

Comment: @Mini I misunderstood. They do not threaten their "first move" they basically move twice the distance of knights (4 up/down, 2 right/left, or, 4 right/left, 2 up/down)

Comment: @Mini But they also move according to the first knight move...

Comment: @Mini Hold on I'll add a picture to help explain.

Comment: A regular knight cannot move to a square with a same coloured piece in it, so you need to explicitly state that the half-way square doesn't have to be empty. Otherwise, you could fit 64 non-threatening speedy knights pretty trivially.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to fit 12 speedy knights onto the board.  These 12 attack every other square on the board, so I think it's unlikely that more than 12 will fit.

[image: 12 Speedy Knights]

Answer (score 7):

I believe I can fit 8 speedy-knights on a board. Indeed, obviously you'd have at least of one colour. Then you'll notice that there's always that pesky diagonal that a knight has trouble getting to:

[image]

Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: It works! I'll give others a while to get 9 or more, if they can't you get Best Answer/Accepted Answer!

Comment: No problem! I really enjoy these puzzles.

Comment: @warspyking how about ticking the answer :p

Comment: Done! Obviously nobody could beat 8. I have expected someone to post 2, one on each colour XD

Answer (score 4):

I can prove that 12 is the best you can do:

First, let's agree to call a move of form $(a, b)$ a move that is $a$ vertical steps and $b$ horizontal steps, or vice-versa.  So, for example, a standard knight move is $(2, 1)$.

Step 1: Notice that a speedy knight can make all moves
$$(2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3), (4, 0), (4, 2),$$
anywhere on the board.  Also, a speedy knight can make any move
$$(1, 1)$$
unless one endpoint of the move is in the corner -- I'll call this the corner exception.

In other words, if a move $(a, b)$ has $a$ and $b$ at most $4$, and same parity, then it is legal unless it is $(2, 2)$, $(4, 4)$ or the corner exception.

Step 2: By symmetry it's enough to show that there can be at most $3$ knights on light-colored squares in the bottom half of the board.  (Notice light- and dark- colored squares don't interact.)  Let's agree to number the columns 1 through 8.

Step 3: Consider two knights on light-colored squares in the bottom half of the board.  The vertical distance between them is at most 3.  I claim the horizontal distance between them can't be 0 (same column), 1 (adjacent columns), 3, or 4, except for the corner exception.  For example if the horizontal distance was 3 then it would either be a $(3, 1)$-move or a $(3, 3)$-move between them, and either way they are attacking each other.  The other cases are easy to check.

Step 4: Note that the corner exception only occurs in columns 7 and 8.  (Remember, we're looking at light-colored squares on the lower half of the board.)

Step 5: We're almost done!  Notice there can be at most:
-one knight in columns 1, 2, 5
-one knight in columns 3, 6, 7
-one knight in columns 4, 8.
Hence, at most three knights total.  The proof is complete.